# What is the most efficient way to host a .NET Core 2.2 API with a Swagger interface and a standalone .Net Core 2.2 Web App with an Angular Front End?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger

I am looking to publish to Azure, two .Net Core 2.2 apps. The .NET core web application is using Angular for it's front end and accessing another project (.NET Core API) for all back end requests. I know that we can push both to a single Azure Application, however, I have Swagger setup on the API so I would like that to be available as well. What recommendations would you give to optimize costs and performance. I can create two Azure applications for each project but wanted to see if it is possible to do it in one.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately like most things the answer is “it depends”. From your description it sounds like you’d want to use azure app service (although a consumption model for azure functions could be cheaper for what you’re tying to do but couldn’t say without more info).

Assuming you use the app service then the cheapest option could in theory be nothing if you used the free tier (and a free database like MySQL in app if you need one) however this limits you to I think 60 minutes of CPU time a day. If you’re just playing around this may be fine.

Next tier up is shared but this also limits you to a specific amount of CPU time, also neither free nor shared can have custom certificates so all together these two tiers aren’t really meant for production systems.

This means the cheapest would be a B1 app service which is available on Linux at its cheapest, best to check the latest prices using the azure calculator. If you go for this then you can effectively add as many apps as you like so having one for your front end and another for your backend would be no problem. That said you could serve both from a single app if you wanted and I’m pretty sure both swagger/OpenApi libraries (Swashbuckle and NSwag) have enough customisation to allow you to specify what appears in your swagger output.